# Displaying FireStore data in a nice way

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display this array in a nice way. Is there a way to ignore the text and just get the values from FireStore. So what I want is when I run the app I only want "jocke" and "5" to show.

```
return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.size,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text('${data.docs[index]['players']}');
                    },
```

https://gyazo.com/ebe5097177204f317921a79a081210a5
https://gyazo.com/fd7b8cf9e25c386667e62416332d5ee2

Answer (score 1):

You will want to access the fields directly after grabbing the overall player object via the index. You will want to do something like this:

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  var player = data['players'][index];
  var name = player['name'];
  var score = player['score'][0];
  return Text('$player - $score');
}
```

This will display the text like this: `jocke - 5`.

Note that score seems to be saved as a list in your example so I took the first element of it since I don't know the context of why it's a list.